# Multiplying Arrays from Two Different Agents yields NullPointException; why?

Tags: anylogic

I have two agent populations, `AgentAs[..]` and `AgentBs[..]`. `AgentAs[]` has a population of 2 while `AgentBs[]` has a population of 100. Each `AgentB` evaluates each `AgentA` by comparing its arrays with those in the `AgentA` currently being checked (the arrays in each agent type are of equal length). `AgentB` calculates the sum of the products of the corresponding elements in each array, then chooses the `AgentA` with the max `sumOfProducts`.

```
double[] Array_AgentA1 = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0};
double[] Array_AgentA2 = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
double[] Array_AgentB1 = new double[]{0.0, 0.85, 0.0};
double sumOfProducts = 0.0;
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException at this line when I try to iterate through and sum the products:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    sumOfProducts += Array_AgentA1[i] * Array_AgentB1[i];
}
```

What's causing the error? Can I not multiply arrays with zeros? They've already been declared and filled with zeros by this point, so they're not empty arrays (I don't think). Not sure how to assess the issue from here (I'm not the strongest java programmer so that might be the issue here). Suggestions are welcome. Thanks

edit:

`sumOfProducts` is a variable in the `AgentB` workspace. `Array_AgentB1` is an array created in a function in `AgentB` workspace. `Array_AgentA1` is a `double[]` type parameter in `AgentA` workspace, created "On startup:" when the AgentA is generated.

Comment: Where are those two code snippets located? Main-> on startup?

Comment: I suspect that this is due to sumOfProducts, not the multiplication itself

Comment: They're in AgentB and this comparison is called from Main

Comment: Drag and drop a variable to the Main called "sumOfProducts". Then delete your initialization in the first snippet `double sumOfProducts = 0.0;`. Let me know if resolves the issue.

Comment: Still throws a NullPointerException. Also, each AgentB would have a unique "sumOfProducts"; this is why I had sumOfProducts at the AgentB level rather than on Main.

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. What do you mean by "this comparison is called from Main"? Which comparison? You mean the loop in the second code?

Comment: If so, you should use `this.sumOfProducts`...

Comment: Something tells me Yashar Ahmadov is right, but you should post your entire code. Your snippet is misrepresenting the code you are executing.

Comment: On Main, I've placed a user control (button) that runs the function to compare the two AgentAs. It's not 'On startup:', it's user-controlled. This comparison function iterates through the population of 100 AgentBs and calculates a sumOfProducts for each of the 2 AgentAs, both of which are unique to each AgentB (so, there are 200 sumOfProducts scores, 2 for each AgentA in each AgentB). Each AgentB then selects the AgentA with the maximum sumOfProducts score.

Comment: I did forget "this." before sumOfProducts, but it still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you place these two codes together..in the same block/cell..you still get error?

Comment: "I've placed a user control (button) that runs the function to compare the two AgentAs" - I suspect you are creating new instances of whatever UI components use these references when clicking this button. So, the initial state of your UI will contain properly initialized arrays, but when you click the button new, null, arrays are created causing the NPEs. Since your code is proprietary and you cannot post it, I can only assume this is the case. That said, you could sanitize your code and still post how this UI is constructed. But I am almost certain your problem is what I described.

Comment: @YasharAhmadov the `AgentA` arrays are created in that agent's workspace. Then, AgentB has a function where in that function's body, it generates its own array, then iterates through the two platforms and calculates `sumOfProducts` for both `AgentAs`.  So, the `AgentB` array and `sumOfProducts` calculations are in the same function body.

Comment: @hfontanez I was worried I'd miss the actual issue with the sanitized snippets I've included already and it's likely that I have. I've added bit more info as an edit. Specifically, the array in `AgentA` is actually a parameter of type double[], whereas the array in `AgentB` is declared and used in the function, it's not a parameter.

Comment: @Vince the problem is either what I posted in my previous comment or what Yashar provided in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to properly initialize the array parameter in `AgentA`. After changing the parameter type to `double[]`, I needed to add `{0,0}` into the initial value box. :-/

Comment: Glad we were of some help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem

```
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        sumOfProducts += Array_AgentA1[i] * Array_AgentB2[i];
    }
```

`Array_AgentB2` is not declared according to your code snippet. If you change it to `Array_AgentB1`, the answer will be 0.85.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I wrote the question. Unfortunately I can't post the entire code (proprietary).

Comment: @Vince, the point is the same. Having zeros in the array has nothing to do with the NPEs you are getting. The problem is elsewhere and your snippet misrepresents (hides) the problem. Therefore, it will be very hard to figure out why. I think the problem is that you may have global and local variables with the same name and, as Yashar Ahmadov suggested, you may be using an uninitialized local variable. If using `this` works, then you know that was the problem.

Comment: I think I found the problem; you're right, it has to do with global and local variables (well, parameters). I'll post an edit if this solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the variable calling and initialization;  it has nothing to do with multiplying zeros. If you are calling Agent A parameter from Agent B, then you should specify that in your loop. For example:`agentAs.get(0).Array_AgentA1`.

And you should use `this.variableName` when assigning values to that specific member of the agent.